# Is there any well known approach when it comes to converting a left linear grammar to a right one?

Tags: compiler-construction, regular-language, formal-languages

I have to solve the following problem for my formal languages course:

> Given a left linear grammar compute the corresponding right linear one

using a program I created. While I am aware about the algorithm how to do that, what I don't really know  is how to approach this problem, how to implement the algorithm. The teacher said I can use whatever language I like, and since C++ is the one I have been doing most of the time, I thought this should be the one. I would like to ask you how would you do this problem, maybe you can give me some general ideas or steps then I shall do the actual exercise. Any idea will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: What stops you from writing down the known algorithm in C++ syntax?

Comment: You must provide more details on what is hampering you. If it's C++ aspects outside your problem domain (memory mgmt, strong data typing, debugging support) use a scripting language, possibly syntactically similar to C++. If you do not know how to turn the algorithm into code, delve into a book like Sedgewick's Algorithms in C++ or an intro to data structures and algorithms. If you have trouble in setting up your dev environment, use an online platform like [ideone](https://ideone.com) ([here](https://arnemertz.github.io/online-compilers/) is a list )